# WordPress Custom Superfish CSS Problem

Tags: css, menus

The problem can be found here: http://themeforward.com/demo2/

Use my menu and navigate to Features > Shortcodes > Typography.  Notice how the border ( `ul .sub-menu { border:1px solid #000 }` ) moves the third level menu item (typography) down one pixel.  How do I get rid of that one pixel gap so that the third level menu item lines up correctly?

Here is my CSS:

```
/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
    float:          left;
    z-index: 900
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color:          #FFF;
    padding:        10px;
    text-decoration:none
}
.sf-menu li {
    margin-right:35px;
    z-index: 900
}
.sf-menu li li {
    z-index: 900;
    background:#FAFAFA
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    background:     #FAFAFA;
    z-index: 900
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu li a:focus, .sf-menu li a:hover, .sf-menu li a:active {
    outline:        0;
    background: #EEE
}
.sf-menu > li:hover, .sf-menu > li.sfHover,
.sf-menu > li a:focus, .sf-menu > li a:hover, .sf-menu > li a:active {
    outline:        0;
    background: #AF1D21
}

.sf-menu .current-post-ancestor a, .sf-menu .current-menu parent a, .sf-menu .current-page-ancestor a, .sf-menf .current-category-ancestor a, .sf-menu .active_category a, .sf-menu .current-menu-item a { color:#1a1a1a }

ul .sub-menu { border:1px solid #000 }
ul li .sub-menu a { color:#262626!important }
ul li .sub-menu a:hover { background:#EEE!important }
```

Comment: This is a CSS question and not a WP question. :)

Comment: Depends if the current-post-ancestor classes are throwing it off at all.  That's not basic CSS, it's related to the WP framework.  Not sure though.  This is kind of a gray area.

Comment: this is entirely css. the ul is a child of an li with a border, so its content is inset the thickness of the border, just like any content in the parent li.

Comment: The classes are purely there for your convenience. The core doesn't have any CSS properties attached to those classes. The classes are blank slates. :)

Comment: I understand how that part of the CSS works... and that's why it isn't making any sense that it gets bumped down by 1 pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this isn't a WP question, you can use the following CSS to get that third level menu to align properly.

```
.sf-menu li li li{
    top:-1px;
}
```

Hope this helps.